# fixed and absolute

Tags: css

I am trying to have a webpage with a parallax screen and on the top a navigation bar. I have tried, everything I know and I cant get it to work.

Comment: It has something to do with the "overflow-y: scroll;" in body. The position:fixed element works like a position:absolute one if you use the overflow-y:scoll on the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by perspective:1px; in the body. Delete that line and position:fixed works but removing the perspective:1px break your parallax. Any transform css will cause position:fixed to revert to position:relative.

> Is this effect on position: fixed necessary? If so, need to go into
>   more detail here about why fixed positioned objects should do this,
>   i.e., that it’s much harder to implement otherwise. See Bug 16328. https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#perspective-property

Instead of putting perspective:1px in the body which effects everything, you could put it in a wrapper div like this:

```
 <div style="scrolling-content">
     ... the bits that scrolls...
 </div>
```

and the css...

```
 .scrolling-content {
      width: 100vw;
      height: calc(100vh - 70px);
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      perspective: 1px;
      margin-top: 70px;
 }
```

The 70px is the height (inclusive of padding) of your navigation bar.

Also set the body

```
body {
     scroll-x:hidden; 
     scroll-y:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the overflow-y option on the style for body.

You could do the following:

Wrap both divs with class="section" in a seperate div, like this:

```
<div id="example">
  <div id="title" class="section header">
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="section1" class="section">
    <div class='text'>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then **remove the overflow options from body** and put them in the style for #example, like this:

```
#example {
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective:1px;
}
```